# Inserting delimiters (comma) in space separated file every n columns using awk

Tags: awk, delimiter

I'm trying to insert two commas in between columns of multiples of 2. For example, for the following input file, I'm trying to print 2 commas in between columns b and c & d and e:-

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

The output should look something like this:-

```
a b , , c d , , e
```

The following code is what I have so far. Note that I also have pattern matching, hence the `/a/`. I used a `for` loop to print the commas with an `if` statement that's supposed to print two commas every two columns, which is what the modulo is for:- :-

`awk '/a/{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf $i" "; if ((i%2)==0) printf " , ,"}' test.txt > blabla.txt`

The results are as below. My `for` loop and pattern matching works just fine but for some reason, the `if` statement isn't being executed and I can't figure out why:-

```
a b c d e , ,
```

Any help or better alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could just modify every other element by changing the initial index and increment value

```
$ awk '/a/{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) $i = $i " , ,"; print}' test.txt
a b , , c d , , e
```

- having `i=2` and `i+=2` avoids manually checking whether the field is even. the loop iteration will be 2,4,6,etc instead of 1,2,3,4,etc
- `$i = $i " , ,"` will append the given string to the field
- `print` this will print the contents of `$0` using OFS(output field separator) as the string to join the fields (default OFS is single space character)
- further reading: [gawk manual - Changing the Contents of a Field](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html#Changing-Fields)

In your attempt, you wanted to have multiple statements inside the for-loop. For that you need to place them inside `{}`

```
$ awk '/a/{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf $i" "; if ((i%2)==0) printf " , ,"}' ip.txt
a b c d e  , ,

$ awk '/a/{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf $i" "; if ((i%2)==0) printf " , ," } }' ip.txt
a b  , ,c d  , ,e
```

But this is still in-efficient - apart from missing space after the second comma, there is extra space after last column. And there's no newline character as well, which could be a problem

Comment: Yours works! Thanks! Do you mind explaining why you opt to start the indexing from 2, and what `$i = $i` does ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sed one-liner may help:

```
 sed -r 's/\s\S\s/&, , /g' file
```

only do substitution on lines contain `a`:

```
sed -r '/a/s/\s\S\s/&, , /g' file
```

For example:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/\s\S\s/&, , /g' <<<"a b c d e"
a b , , c d , , e
```

Comment: Will try this out. I've never actually used sed before but it looks a lot shorter than the awk ones. Thanks!

Comment: note that `\s` is not portable and the solution is rather specific to single character fields.. `-E` is more portable than `-r` and not needed here anyway.. also, OP wants to print only lines having `a`, so it should be `sed -n '/a/s/\s\S\s/&, , /gp'`

Comment: @Sundeep oh, if OP only needs the `a` line to be printed, yes, the `-n` and `p` are needed.